Second derivative terms of DFT functional
Given the density functional to KSF matrix elements
$E^{XC} = \int dr f(r,R)$,
where $r$ and $R$ denotes electronic and nuclear coordinates, respectively.
Suppose we have an LDA functional, which can be generalised as
$f(r,R) = f\left(\rho^{\alpha}(r,R), \rho^{\beta}(r,R)\right)$,
where $\alpha$ and $\beta$ denotes spin up and down, respectively.
The resulting contribution to KSF matrix is
$F_{\mu \nu}^{\alpha; \mathrm{LDA}}(R) = \frac{\partial E^{XC}}{\partial P^{\alpha}_{\nu \mu}} = \int dr \frac{\partial f(r,R)}{\partial \rho^{\alpha}} \phi^{*}_{\mu}(r,R) \phi_{\nu}(r,R)$.
If one performs derivative of above w.r.t. $R$, one gets:
$F^{\alpha; \mathrm{LDA}'}_{\mu \nu}(R) = \sum\limits_{\lambda \sigma} \sum_\limits{\xi = \alpha, \beta} \frac{\partial^2f(r,R)}{\partial \rho^{\xi} \rho^{\alpha}} \phi^{*}_{\mu}(r,R) \phi_{\nu}(r,R) \phi^{*}_{\lambda}(r,R) \phi_{\sigma}(r,R) \frac{\partial P^{\xi}_{\sigma \lambda}}{\partial R}$,
where $P$ is density matrix.
Suppose we have a restricted case where $\alpha$ and $\beta$ spin orbitals are identical, should $\frac{\partial^2 f(r,R)}{\partial \rho^{\beta} \rho^{\alpha}} = 0$ be the case or not?

You're probably better off asking this in https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/

This is not an authoritative answer, I've been out of quantum chem for a while.
It would appear that $\frac{\partial^2 f(r,R)}{\partial \rho^{\beta} \rho^{\alpha}} = 0$ does not hold in general. It holds for exchange LDA, because the two spin components are treated independently. For correlation LDA, NWChem goes through the trouble of calculating the following term for PW91LDA:
         Amat2(n,D2_RA_RB) = Amat2(n,D2_RA_RB)
     &        + (d1edrho(1) + d1edrho(2) + rhoval*d2edrho(2))*fac

which should be the second derivative referenced before (assuming quasi-standard notation of variables). The relevant file is xc_pw91lda.F, lines 347f. The NWChem developers would not spend computational time calculating a zero in the general case.
Note that there is a trick showing that you do not need second order derivatives for the nuclear gradient, but I don't have the reference on hand. Googling yielded this paper, relevant section 5.3, which attributes Pulay. The underlying math should be the same for DFT.

I have confirmed this is true. I had my LDA- $\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial \rho^{\beta} \partial \rho^{\alpha}}$ obtained using LIBXC package, for restricted and unrestricted case the second derivative terms are hard-coded and approx. calculated zeros for every quadrature point, respectively (note this is only for LDA functional).
